# How to get FGETCSV to read entire Japanese cell

Tags: php, encoding, fgetcsv

I have a large study conducted with about 50 questions and 70,000 entries, so manually editing or using pivot tables just won't really work, I need to upload the data into a database. I can't get the Japanese characters to be read with any accuracy while using fgcsv(). I've tried setting the locale to UTF-8 and SJIS, but neither one seem to want to read all of the Japanese characters. I read somewhere this might be a bug, but I don't know..

The data looks like this:

```
Q-004   必須回答    あなたは、以下のどちらにお住まいですか？    S/A
1       北海道 Hokkaido
2       青森県 Aomori
3       岩手県 Iwate
4       宮城県 Miyagi
5       秋田県 Akita
```

Here is my code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ja_JP.SJIS');
        $fp = fopen($_POST["filename"],'r') or die("can't open file");
            $csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024);
            $query = "";
            $count = 0;
            $question = false;
            while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024)) {

                if (!$question && strpos($csv_line[0],"Q-")!== false)
                {
                    echo "Found a question: ".$csv_line[2] . "<br>";
                    $question = true;
                }
                else if($question && strlen($csv_line[0])==0)
                {
                    echo "<hr>";
                    $question = false;
                }
                else if($question && intval($csv_line[0])>0)
                {
                    echo $csv_line[0]. " has value ". $csv_line[2]." - ".$csv_line[3]. "<br>";
                }       

                $count++;
            }
        echo "$count records read successfully";
        fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
```

Here is the result:

```
Found a question: A以下のどちらにお住まいですか？
1 has value k海道 - Hokkaido
2 has value X県 - Aomori
3 has value - Iwate
4 has value {城県 - Miyagi
5 has value H田県 - Akita
```

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to reading a CSV in PHP, I would say... don't do it, and use an SQL database instead, wherein you can set a collation such as **ujis_japanese_ci** in MySQL.

You should be able to easily import your CSV into a MySQL database using phpMyAdmin, if that is what you have, and then render the data from the MySQL database instead of reading a CSV file.

It is a work-around, granted, but my general experience is that CSV + foreign/special characters == problems.

I believe it is at least worth the try. Good luck

Comment: I would like to import it using phpMyAdmin, but, as I said, I have 50 questions to import, they're on 1 sheet in a workbook, and not all of the arrays are the same "shape". In the example, I used a single answer, but I have some questions that are multi-answer and some that are matrices, which I was planning to implement as I read the CSV. I suppose I could just toss all the japanese, import it, and then make a new table with japanese->english translations.

Comment: In any event, yes, I would go with the SQL approach and toss the CSV. It would probably make sense to tabulate the data now to make future changes and working with the database easier.

Comment: I'll try this out later and let you know how it works. Just to clarify, the data is already tabulated, I'm just trying to find an easy way to store the keys to the data. Originally I was thinking to just hard code the values as arrays so when I pull the data from the db via php, the data size is very small and I don't have to transfer "static" data every time.